# Cambiar el icono de mi posición en el mapa usando OsmDroid

Tags: java, android-studio, map, bitmap, icons

Estoy usando Osmdroid para el mapa en una actividad, pero no puedo cambiar el icono predeterminado de una persona amarilla. Actualmente estoy intentando esto, pero no se muestra nada en el mapa.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_truck);
mLocationOverlay.setPersonIcon(bitmap);
map.getOverlays().add(mLocationOverlay);
```

en la consola esto sale esto.

```
E/OsmDroid: error dispatchDraw, probably in edit mode
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
    at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(BaseCanvas.java:54)
    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:226)
    at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:78)
```

Comment: El error se presenta en otro punto de tu código, específicamente donde usas el método isRecycled() , te sugiero agregar esta información , saludos.

Comment: esta dentro del onCreate(), agradecería si tuvieras un ejemplo de como cambiar el icono.

Comment: Te sugiero agregues lo que realizas en el código, recuerda que tienes que agregar la información necesaria para que la comunidad te ayude, [ask], saludos.